# How can entities maintain their control of their avatars across dimensions?

Tags: biology, alternate-worlds, gods

Our reality is separated from the god realm through a veil that functions as a barrier. As the physical and metaphysical realms operate by different rules, the veil prevents them from interacting. The only way for a god to influence the mortal world is through an avatar.

An avatar takes the form of a physical humanoid that is built using godtech. After this body is designed, it is summoned to the mortal realm, retaining the deity's abilities. The god is supposed to be able to control this body from the alternate realm, and is able to interact with mortals.

However, there is a problem. Once the body is in the physical realm, it is subject to the barrier, which prevent the world's from interacting. The artificial body loses its connection to the god dimension, cutting it off from the gods control. This defeats the purpose of the whole thing, as the body is now just some bag of fleshy material that cannot be manuvered.

The gods need a way to maintain some interface between themselves and their artificially created bodies to maintain the connection between each other. How can this be made to happen?

Comment: How would any sufficiently crafted technobabble distinguish itself from any other technobabble when it comes to determining the quality of answers to this question? This looks to be entirely opinion based.

Comment: Your world, you make the rules, so I don't see why a *god* can't do that other than *you* just decided they can't for no reason.  In the second paragraph you say gods *can* interact with mortals (and that means the physical world) and in the third paragraph a "barrier" somehow prevents this.  Only you know why the barrier works sometimes but not others.  Makes no sense to me.

Comment: Not an answer, I'm too hungry. The god places a copy of it's consciousness into the avatar. If the avatar can pass through, then periodically a brief microscopic opening can be made to allow a two-way update.

Comment: I’m very tempted to write an answer using condoms as an analogy, but I’m not sure I’d be able to avoid the inevitable euphemisms long enough for it be any good...

Answer (score 3):

That's a very interesting conundrum.

One solution I can think of is that the gods don't retain direct control over their godbods. Instead, they imbue the body with a sliver of their consciousness. The resulting body would make decisions just as if the god was controlling it(because a part of the god is controlling the body).
An interesting thing to note is that the godbod would increasingly deviate from the original persona the longer it existed as it gains experiences in the mortal world.

A direct-contact solution could be to utilize quantum entanglement. Maybe the gods have very good quantum entanglement and can build a computer that operates in two different realities, but the entanglement keeps them connected. These computers may have limited lifespans, as there is no way to re-establish a quantum field(that I know of) in particles from different dimensions.

Comment: +1 for the first point, there's a great example of this in the Dresden books https://dresdenfiles.fandom.com/wiki/Lash

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic resupply issue. You have a resource, divine tier bodies, and a remote location you can't easily access. This is a common issue in exploring remote regions. There are several ways around it.

1. You can make the divine avatars autonomous. They have directives and commands and abilities to do what you want. You build them for whatever situation, depending on the whim of the god, and they go out and do their thing.
2. You can give updates in future divine body deliveries, if your avatars go rogue. Software updates are important for when there are issues.
3. If you can get enough tech there you can build a portal/ spying device from the mortal realm to the divine realm. Then, the golems can look at the divine realm for updates and to see what to do, and the mortals can send useful resources like the slain bodies of other gods back to their god.
4. You can have a third, neutral location that you can send updates to like heaven, hell, purgatory, whatever. Just because you can't access each other's realm doesn't mean you can't access a third realm. This realm may require building, or joining a group that has access to one like a pantheon.

Answer (score 0):

Communication can't go through the barrier; however it might be possible to throw something at the barrier from one side that causes a perceptible change in the barrier (probably some sort of wave) that can be picked up and interpreted from the other side.

- Build transmitter devices that send some sort of energy into the interdimensional veil, causing it to resonate or change in some recognizable manner.
- Build receiver devices that pick up such resonations.
- Build your avatar. Give it a transmitter and receiver. Keep a transmitter and receiver for yourself.
- Deploy your avatar. You can now remotely control it and nothing "crosses the veil".